# Check file for count of records using subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

If file has only one one row then send error message. I'm using Python 2.6.9 version. Below is my code. I get the count of rows but if condition doesn't work.

```
import os
import subprocess
count=subprocess.Popen('wc -l <20170622.txt', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

if count.communicate() == 1: 
    sys.exit("File has no data - 20170622.txt")
```

I tried different method to make the if condition work but there was no luck.
Here I want to check if file has more than one row . If it doesn't have more than one row than I have to send error message.

Comment: Is subprocess really necessary here? What's wrong with `if len(open(filename).readlines()) > 1:`? Other than not closing the file after opening it, that is.

Comment: @Kevin If you think about it, wc is a lot faster than opening a massive file in memory and creating a list out of its contents, emphasis on massive.

Comment: Thanks Kevin , it worked. @Coldspeed I would like to understand what I made wrong while using subprocess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

count = Popen("wc -l <20170622.txt", shell=True, stdout=PIPE)

if count.wait() == 0:                        # 0 means success here
    rows = int(count.communicate()[0])       # (stdout, stderr)[0]
    if rows == 1:                            # only one row
        # do something...       
else: 
    print("failed")                          # assume anything else to be failure
```

`Popen` returns 0 on success, so first we have to check if the command run successfully: `count.wait()`--wait until process is finished and return its exit code.

Comment: Thanks for catching that mistake. +1.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, `process.communicate()` returns a tuple. The part you are interested in, is the first part, since this contain stdout. In addition, it is normally better to not use `shell=True` in `Popen`. It can be rewritten, using by using an open file descriptor as stdin. This gives you a program like (using Python 3):

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

input_file = '20170622.txt'

myinput = open(input_file)
with open(input_file, 'r') as myinput, Popen(['wc', '-l'], stdin = myinput, stdout=PIPE) as count:

    mystdout, mystderr = count.communicate()
    lines = int(mystdout.strip())
    print(lines)

    if lines <= 1: 
        sys.exit("File has no data - {}".format(input_file))
```

Comment: Thank you @JohanL .